# Why does making window background transparent mess up the layout?

Tags: extjs, background, extjs4, window, transparent

I was able to make the window background transparent with baseCls, but then the layout is messed up.

How to avoid that?

```
.myclass .x-window {
    background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 1);
}

Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        title: 'Hello',
        height: 400,
        itemId: 'mywin',
        width: 600,
        baseCls: 'myclass',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Show MessageBox',
            listeners: {
                click: function() {                
                    Ext.Msg.prompt('Name', 'Please enter your name:', function(btn, text){
                        if (btn == 'ok'){
                            // process text value and close...
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }]
    }).show();
});
```

Comment: Don't modify the baseCls. Use either `cls` or `componentCls`. It won't work anyway, because `myclass` will be added to the element, so the selector will never match. It would need to be `myclass.x-window`.

Answer (score 0):

Changing baseCls actually changes the x-window to myclass, causing all of the layout related css tied to .x-window class from Ext's base theme css files (possibly the default-theme-all.css depending on what you set the base theme to be) to not be applied. This is why your layout is breaking.

As Evan suggested, use cls instead. Your css can simply be .myclass { background-color: yourcolor; } in that case.

Edit: Oh and to add to that, you will likely need to set .myclass .x-window-body, and .myclass .x-window-header to have transparent backgrounds as well if you want the whole window transparent. Not sure what you are going for.